# How can I get all dates in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

```
select date(p.date_of_sale) as "Date", r.reservation_id as "Reservation ID",
pt.name as "Product Type", scn.name as "Sale Channel",
(CASE WHEN nullif(r.company_id,0)=0 THEN 'B2C Customer' ELSE ca.name END) as "Company Account",
ct.name as "Class Type", op.name as "Operator", p.description as "Product Description",
Count(case when p.product_type_id = 6 then p.id end) as "No of Car_Rentals"
from products as p
join reservations as r on p.reservation_id = r.id  
left join companies as ca on ca.id = r.company_id
left join class_types as ct on ct.id = ca.class_type_id
join product_types as pt on pt.id = p.product_type_id 
join sales_categories as sc on sc.id = p.sales_category_id
join sales_channels as scn on scn.id = r.sales_channel_id
join operators as op on op.id = p.operator_id 
where date(p.date_of_sale) >= '2021-06-01' 
and date(p.date_of_sale) <= current_date
and p.sales_category_id = 1
and p.status_id = 7 
and p.product_type_id = 6 
group by date(p.date_of_sale), r.reservation_id, pt.name, scn.name, r.company_id, ca.name, ct.name, op.name, p.description
order by date(p.date_of_sale) desc
```

I try this code and that works like that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ekC.png). But I want to get a list of all dates even though we don't have sales for that day. How can I change my query,please?

Answer (score 0):

Here you could left join your query to *generate_series()* call:

```
select t.d, q.*
from
  generate_series('2021-06-01'::timestamp, current_date, '1 day'::interval) as t(d)
  left join (<your query>) q on t.d = q."Date"
order by t.d
```

Comment: When I run like that, I got all null values. Except column name d. @Pavel Kulakov